# How to find an object in arraylist by one of it's element and print it?

Tags: java

I am developing a console application where I can register items. Each item has 3 properties serial number, model, year.
I have 3 classes Laptop, Laptops(arraylist) and Office to run the application.
So far I have managed to find the object itself by index number, but i need to list all objects with the property typed in.

This is how I ask user to choose the option

```
Laptops inHouse = new Laptops();
model = Console.askModel("Enter Model : ");
inHouse.findModel(model);
break;
```

That is the find method in Laptops class

```
public void findModel(String aModel)
{
    int arraySize = laptops.size();
    for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
        if (laptops.get(i).getModel() == aModel) {
            System.out.println(laptops.get(i));
        }
    }       
}
```

this is the askModel method in Console class.

```
public static String askModel(String aModel)
{
    System.out.println(aModel);
    String model = askString("Enter the model: ");
    return model;
}
```

Additionally, I am quite new to java, I understand the concept but still struggling on many thing so If I forgot to post a code which is needed to solve the problem I am sorry in advnace.

Comment: You can't just duplicate your findModal function for the other properties?

Answer (score 2):

`findModel` is fine except for your `String` comparison which checks for object equality instead of `String` equality, change the comparison to:

```
if (laptops.get(i).getModel().equals(aModel))
```

For non-primitives, equality tests using `==` check if the object is literally identical (that it's the same *instance*), whereas [`String.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) will compare the actual String value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with the String.equals

Answer (score 0):

You might want a HashMap instead of an ArrayList:

```
import java.util.HashMap

public class Laptops{
    Map<String, Laptop> laptops = new HashMap<String, Laptop>();
    //alternatively if java 7, do "= new HashMap<>();" instead

    public Laptop findModel(Laptop aModel){
        Laptop theModel = laptops.get(aModel);
        return theModel;
    }
```

To put the models in, you'll use the `put` method of HashMap:

```
public void addAModel(String modelName, Laptop aModel){

    laptops.put(modelName, aModel);
}
```

This way if you know a model's name (a String), it will return you the `Laptop` object you're after.